# CSS div table line with dynamic sizes

Tags: html, css, dynamic, cross-browser, css-tables

Here's what I need. It's fully crossbrowseer (if add some styles)
http://jsfiddle.net/Jkz5f/8/
but it's not good solution, because used constant positions

And this line with floats
http://jsfiddle.net/Jkz5f/5/
but if you add "b" string it's will be crash

Does anyone know fully-crossbrowser solution
without (display:table) and without constant margins for ".b"?

Comment: Dare I wade into this one? If you intend this for tabular data then surely an old-school actual table would suffice.

Answer (score 0):

using  elements as divs isn't a good idea. Just do this:

```
<div id="table">
            <div class="tr">
                <div class="a"><a href="#">a</a></div>
                <div class="b"><a href="#">bbbbbbbbbb</a></div>
<!-- and so on -->
            </div>
    </div>
```

of couse, add all the columns you need. Then float everything to the left and add a clear:both to .a, .b ,.c divs OR do this:

```
<div id="table">
            <div class="tr">
                <div class="a"><a href="#">a</a></div>
                <div class="b"><a href="#">bbbbbbbbbb</a></div>

<!-- and so on -->
            <div style="clear:both"></div>
            </div><!-- end of row -->
    </div>
```